# Debugging Javascript/Angular issue when you can't recreate it

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to coding, working on an open source financial calculator in Angular 6.

Some users are reporting an issue that I can't recreate on any of my devices/browsers.

The "submit" button on my form has a mousedown function that changes their cursor to a waiting cursor and provides a "calculating..." message.

```
<button type="submit" id="maximizeSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" (mousedown)="waitCursor()">Submit</button>

waitCursor() {
document.getElementById("container").style.cursor = "wait";
document.getElementById("maximizeSubmit").style.cursor = "wait";
this.statusMessage = "Calculating the optimal strategy..."
}
```

Then upon submission the form triggers an onSubmit method. That method basically runs a bunch of math, reports back a result, then changes the cursor back to normal and removes the "calculating..." message.

```
<form #inputForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

onSubmit() {
//lots of math
document.getElementById("container").style.cursor = "default";
document.getElementById("maximizeSubmit").style.cursor = "default";
this.statusMessage = ""
}
```

Several users are reporting that when the "submit" button is clicked, the "calculating" message only appears for as long as they have the button pressed, then it disappears. And the calculator never outputs any result.

But I can't recreate the problem myself. Nor can I see what output they're getting in Console to perhaps guide me.

Does anybody have suggestions on how to proceed in such a situation?

The actual site and its GitHub page are below, in case that's helpful for any reason:
https://opensocialsecurity.com/
https://github.com/MikePiper/open-social-security

Comment: Return as "Cannot reproduce" get info on their browser versions, exact steps, etc. This isn't really in a form we can help with yet. SO is not a debugging service

Comment: At first glance I would want to know more details about the users environments whom are experiencing this issue. What browser, what OS, what versions etc. My first guess would be they're using unupdated pre ES6 non "evergreen" browsers that don't support `let` and `const` so your code isn't being interpreted correctly....but like @BradleyDotNET pointed out, it's a pretty broad issue & question to tackle by just saying "hey here's my source, find what's wrong?" and no minimal example to reproduce ;)

Comment: Thanks BradleyDotNET and Chris W. I wasn't so much expecting somebody to solve the problem as just looking for guidance on steps I should take so I can work toward solving it myself. (Again, super new to coding so processes aren't obvious to me.)

Thanks for your input/time.

Comment: I suggest just moving the 'wait' styling into the onSubmit() function or just call waitCursor() in onSubmit() instead of triggering two events from one action.

Comment: That style of question doesn't fit very well here; reading [ask] may help, also please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Oh and just for other readers and another potential gotcha, if it's say internet explorer issues you may need to go into your polyfills.js file and un-comment specific polyfills for certain prototypical methods, that's another common culprit.

Answer (score -1):

Like guys mentioned, you should got somehow info in what browser, OS, etc... did that happened. If you could find that out, definitely do it that way.

In apps with larger user base where you can't communicate with users about their errors that well or you want to know about errors they have and they even don't know about, you should implement and connect your app to some kind of Error logger. Nice article about it is [here](https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a), especially chapter "How to keep track of the errors". Then you will know about all unexpected exceptions and in which environment they happened.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Lukas! That's not something I would have thought of.